# turning 3 leds on/off using serial port

Tags: arduino

I am trying to write a program that will do the following :

Write code so that if 1 then enter pressed or send clicked, and then 1 again and enter pressed or send clicked causes LED one to turn on, if ‘1’ ‘0’ is entered in a similar way then LED 1 turns off, and so on for LEDs two and three, ie: ‘2’ ‘1’ turns on LED 2, ‘3’ ’0’ turns off LED 3.

So far here is my code:

```
int incomingVal;
int ledPin = 16; 
int ledPin2 = 15; 
int ledPin3 = 14; 

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.println("starting");
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin3,OUTPUT);
}


void checkForRecvdChar (); 

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0 ) //then chars are in the serial buffer
  {
    incomingVal = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.print("You entered: ");
    Serial.println(incomingVal);

    if (incomingVal == 10);//turns off led 1 
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  

    }

     if (incomingVal == 11);//turns on led 1 
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  

    }

     if (incomingVal == 20);//turns off led 2
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, LOW);  

    }

     if (incomingVal == 21);//turns on led 2
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin2, HIGH);  

    }

     if (incomingVal == 30);//turns off led 3
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, LOW);  

    }

     if (incomingVal == 31);//turns on led 3
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);  

    }

  }

}
```

Right now it turns all LEDs on no matter what combination I enter

Answer (score 2):

you've got semi colons after your `if` statements,  which terminates the `if` statement. So all your intended `if` blocks get executed.

for example...

```
if (incomingVal == 31);//turns on led 3
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);  

    }
```

needs to be

```
  if (incomingVal == 31)
    {
      digitalWrite(ledPin3, HIGH);  

    }
```

Comment: The "You entered: " shows the the first integer I entered and then shows the second one , For example when I type 1,1 it displays:
starting
You entered: 1
You entered: 1

Comment: So far I just removed the semicolons

Comment: which shows its not reading 11, so you need to sort out reading the right numbers from serial

Answer (score 0):

```
 Ok So First It Will Better To Use Switch Case in this Case:
1. You Can Just Use The Same Number To Turn The Led ON and OFF 
Example:

    case 1:
        {
            if(wFlag == false)
            {
               digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
               wFlag = true;
               Serial.println("LED is ON");
            }
            else if (wFlag == true)
            {
                digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
                wFlag = false;
                Serial.println("LED is OFF");
            }
            break;
         }

2. The Way You Do It, Your Problem Is Serial Read Gets Only Byte after Byte
   So When You Press 1 or 11 It Sees 1 Because It is The First one "1" and Then Do Your If             
   Statment.
   You Can Fix it Like This: 

        while (Serial.available())
        {
            IncomingData = Serial.parseInt();
             Temp += String(IncomingData);    //Temp String Var
        }
       DataIN = Temp.toInt();  //DataIN int Var
       Temp ="";                         // Rest The Temp String
        Switch(DataIN)           //  Or if(DataIN == 1)
        {

        }
```